# Adding dateframe to PDF using Reportlab python

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to display my date frame in a pdf using Lab Report. I have figured out so far what I want but I do not know how to add the index so this is missing. My pdf looks like this:
My data frame:

```
            00-04  04-08  08-12  12-16  16-20  20-24
2017-12-09  17671  16443  14300  15317  16398  16398
2017-12-10  16632  17611  16486  10562  10562  13014
2017-12-11  11355      0      0      0   8569  11697
```

My code:

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import *
from reportlab.lib import colors
import pandas as pd
import random

PATH_OUT = "C:\\"

elements = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("Analysis_Lists.pdf", pagesize=A3, rightMargin=30,leftMargin=30, topMargin=30,bottomMargin=18)
elements.append(Paragraph("Wind Park Available Flex Neg", styles['Title']))

data = [[random.random() for i in range(1,4)] for j in range (1,8)]
df = resultado(lista,df_output,labels)
lista = [df.columns[:,].values.astype(str).tolist()] + df.values.tolist()

ts = [('ALIGN', (1,1), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
     ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (-1,0), 1, colors.black),
     ('LINEBELOW', (0,0), (-1,0), 1, colors.black),
     ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,0), 'Times-Bold'),
     ('LINEBELOW', (0,-1), (-1,-1), 1, colors.black),
     ('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.white),
     ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.black)]

table = Table(lista, style=ts)
s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["BodyText"]
s.wordWrap = 'CJK'
Explanation = [["The lost HT flex in the last week for 50 Hz SRL is ."],
["The lost HT flex in the last week for Tennet SRL is "],
["The lost HT flex in the last week for Amprion SRL is "],
]

data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, s) for cell in row] for row in Explanation]
e=Table(data2,spaceAfter=20)

elements.append(table)
elements.append(e)
```

I have added columns and values but not sure how to add an index and my index is DateTime stamp:

```
l = df.index[:,].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
l = l.tolist()
l = [u'2017/12/09', u'2017/12/10', u'2017/12/11']
```

Can someone give me a hint how to continue with this process? I am not familiar with reportlab. Any help or suggestion would be great I have read *Report Lab user guide*

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Do you already have the index or are you trying to create it? What would be your desired result to look like?

Comment: @MattR I am just missing the index in my pdf table as the first column. I will add how it is looking right now and the user can not see the dates, for example represented by the index.

Comment: so you want the index of the dataframe to be a column instead?

Comment: I want to include the index in lista, so the user can see the dates @MattR

Comment: what happens when you run this? `df_2 = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'date'})` and now pass `df2` into `lista` instead of `df`

Comment: Yeah, I thoguht about it when you said. i will try now and lets see if works.

Comment: @MattR it worked it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I think the `PDF` problem is a "Red-Herring". I think the true issue is just getting your index into the columns.

```
df_2 = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'date'}) 
#.rename is just renaming 'index' into 'date'. you can put anything you want in there
```

and now pass `df2` into `lista` instead of `df`.

The rest of the code will work as expected.